# How realistic are the scenarios outlined in my course?

Tags: arbitrage, no-arbitrage-theory, forward-rate

I am currently taking a course in Financial Mathematics as part of my Maths degree. Many of the covered topics are quite basic, and revolve around potential arbitrage opportunities. For example, consider the following scenario:

[image: question]

Looking at part c) of this question, we deduce that the investor can make a guaranteed profit of $\$ 71.61$, with no risk.

In real market situations, do arbitrage opportunities like this exist, or does the No-Arbitrage Principle always hold?

Comment: In real market situations the players are always looking for opportunities like this (it is a way of thinking that becomes almost an obsession). As a result the opportunities that you can still find are small, and they don't last long. The elimination of Arbitrage Opportunities is an ongoing *process*, which however never perfectly reach its goal. A professor of mine said: "it is not that there are no free lunches, but that the free lunches quickly get eaten".

Comment: @AlexC and also, people can have different opinions on what constitutes a free lunch...